# Can I display a site page in the sidebar in Sharepoint foundation 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have a Sharepoint Foundation 2010 install that is working very well. My current problem is that I have a number of subsites and pages that are all set to have 1 column plus sidebar. I have just used the content editor to show the sidebar links and pictures that I want but have had a horrible thought, that if I want to change it down the track, I will need to modify each page individually.

I was wondering if anyone can let me know if I can create a sidebar page under the main site and then show it somehow in the sidebar of the other pages? I tried using the webpage viewer but that displays the entire sharepoint site :(

Any ideas would be gratefully recieved :)

cheers
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood your question. But feel free to point out if I am missing anything. You can achieve this the following ways.

1. Use a Reusable Content List and web part - This web part can be added to any number of pages you need and if created in the root site collection, it reads data from the Reusable content list in the root website. In this case, if you have an update in the future, you just nee to update the central list with the data and all the pages having the web part automatically gets these updates. I found an article which might help you in understanding - http://blog.funknstyle.com/?p=577
2. There is another way of adding a Custom List, then creating a page with the CQWP, which would not only gives the same functionality as above, but also helps you in creating additional filters to display data if required. This way also is quiet cool. Check this article for detailed explanation - http://www.sharepointblog.co.uk/2012/05/create-a-reusable-web-part/

Good Luck ...

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Create the desired content in a CEWP (as you have), then edit the html of that CEWP, copy it and paste it into Notepad. Save as a txt file. Upload that txt file to a document library in the top level site.

On the sub-sites, create CEWPs and use the "Link to file" option in the web part properties to link to that text file.

Now you have only one source for many CEWPs and if you change that one txt file, the changes will instantly be reflected in all the CEWPs that link to the file.